# Compare the contents of two cells and format the differences between them in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

What would be the best way to compare the contents of two different cells and format the differences by changing the color of what's different in each cell?

The picture below is an example of what I want. In the example below `Computer`, `Dog` and `Cup` must be highlighted as being different. The formatting must happen while pasting new content or while typing.

Any suggestions?

[image]

FYI - The data entered in each cell will be separated by dashes as shown in the picture below.

EDIT: Changed the picture to show the right format, `Original` mismatch the `After Formatted` example.

Comment: Look at this query,very very similar i believe. [Identify the Words if its matches highlight the value VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217839/identify-the-words-if-its-matches-highlight-the-value-vba)

Comment: I don't think is the same, in that thread they want to find certain words between some cells, in my case I want to compare the contents of two cells and highlight the difference.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah that is correct, but you can make use of it by making some necessary changes, believe it would work.

Comment: You may be right; I'll take a close look at it and see if I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: The second cell of the original contains "car-dog-HOUSE-cup", the second cell of the formatted contains "car-dog-PHOTO-cup". Was that the intent?

Comment: Oh shoot, no that was not the intent, I meant to put the same items in both examples, I have updated the picture. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem becomes simpler if we think about it in reverse, we redden both cells and then blacken only the parts they share. Dashes between two red parts will also be red.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Call ΗighlightDiff(Me.Range("C1"), Me.Range("C2"))
   Call ΗighlightDiff(Me.Range("C4"), Me.Range("C5"))
End Sub

' this public Sub can reside in a shared module

Public Sub ΗighlightDiff(rnga As Range, rngb As Range, _
                         Optional sep as String = "-", _
                         Optional difColor As Long = vbRed)
   Dim va As Variant, sa As String, sb As String
   Dim p As Long, ln As Long, c As Long
   
   va = Split(rnga, sep)
   rnga.Font.Color = difColor
   rngb.Font.Color = difColor
   If rnga.Value2 = vbNullString Or rngb.Value2 = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
   ' we search "-some-" to not find "some" in "somevalue"
   sa = sep & rnga.Value2 & sep
   sb = sep & rngb.Value2 & sep
   
   For c = LBound(va) To UBound(va)
      p = InStr(1, sb, sep & va(c) & sep)
      If p > 0 Then
         ' Debug.Print va(c), "exists in", sb
         If p > 1 Then p = p - 1
         ln = Len(va(c))
         rngb.Characters(p, ln + IIf(p > 1, 2, 1)).Font.Color = vbBlack
         p = InStr(1, sa, sep & va(c) & sep)
         If p > 1 Then p = p - 1
         rnga.Characters(p, ln + IIf(p > 1, 2, 1)).Font.Color = vbBlack
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

[image]